# OneSignal notifications stopped working after changing package names

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, onesignal

I recently changed all of the package names in my app and thought I had updated all of the external consoles that needed them as well, but apparently not.

When i send out notifications from the onesignal dashboard they appear as sent but none of my test devices are receiving them.

I have updated my package names in the google api console here:
[image]

But they still wont work, have I missed anything?

Comment: need to change sender id on backend server

Answer (score 0):

When changing your package name, you should set up a new OneSignal app and follow the setup steps again.

Combining users from apps with different package names under a single OneSignal app_id is not supported by OneSignal and can cause various bugs like this.